# Find the indices of anti-diagonal elements of a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a `m by n` matrix in matlab and want to find the indices (row, column) of each antidiagonal elements. For example for a `4x3` matrix, I would like to have the following indices:

```
antidiag1 = (1,1)
antidiag2 = (2,1) , (1,2)
antidiag3 = (3,1) , (2,2), (1,3)
antidiag4 = (4,1) , (3,2), (2,3)
antidiag5 = (4,2) , (3,3)
antidiag3 = (4,3)
```

in the above example `(m,n)=(row, column)`. To show what I mean by anti-diagonal elements see the below matrix in which red lines are anti-diagonals

[image]

How to find the indices?

Comment: Can you describe how you define the diagonal for a non-square matrix? Also, anidiagonal elements are the elements of the diagonal who is from the right-top to left-bottom, you may want to tidy up your terminology.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have added an example for anti-diagonal elements for a more clear explanation

Comment: The simple solution would be to mirror the matrix horizontally (`flip`), then use `diag`. The more complex but performant solution is to directly find those indices. Note that for each diagonal, the x and y index of each element sum up to the same number.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I want the index , (row, column), of elements for each antidiagonal

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to extract the elements is to mirror the matrix horizontally, then find the regular diagonals:

```matlab
out = diag( flip(in, 2), k );
```

`k` here is 0 for the main diagonal, positive for diagonals above the main, and negative for those below, see [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html).

---

To find the indices themselves is a bit more complex. You’d start with a loop to generate candidate pairs, then figure out which pairs are valid:

- The first pair is `i=1-k`, `j=n`, with `n` the width of the matrix and `k` the desired diagonal.
- Then you iteratively subtract 1 from `j` and add 1 to `i`, until `j` is 1.
- Finally you remove the pairs where `i` is smaller than 1 or larger than `m`, the height of the matrix.

This process doesn’t really require a loop, the loop process can be vectorized. Still, it’s easier to describe this way.

In code we could write that as follows (untested!):

```matlab
[m,n] = size(A);
i = (1:n)-k;
j = n:-1:1;
invalid = (i < 1) | (i > m);
i(invalid) = [];
j(invalid) = [];
```

Comment: This solution gives the elements their selves. I want the indices, rows and columns.

Comment: @user2983136 I’m away from my computer, so cannot write actual code, but the process I outlined should do the trick.

Comment: @user2983136 Ok, added some untested code. The more I thought about it, the simpler it got. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following script is a solution to this question and works well for square and rectangular 2D matrices

```
clear all;close all;clc

A1=randi([-10 10],3,4)

sz1=size(A1)
        
nA2=reshape([1:1:prod(sz1)],sz1)

nd=sum(sz1)     % amount diagonals

C1={}   % init result cell

for k=-floor(nd/2):1:floor(nd/2)

    a2 = diag( flip(nA2, 2), k )
    [row,col]=ind2sub(sz1,a2)
    C1={C1{:} [row col]}

end

C1(1)=[]  % sought indexes

for k=1:1:size(C1,2)

    C1{k}

end
```

The solution is contained in cell `C1`

In MATLAB to read the actual contents of cell elements use curly brackets indexing, like this

```
 C1{1}
    =
     3     4

 C1{2}
    =
     2     4
     3     3

C1{3}
    =
     1     4
     2     3
     3     2
```

When indexing with conventional parentheses MATLAB returns the sought elements but inside a cell type

```
C2(2)

 1×1 cell array
 {2×2 double}
```

To access individual pairs of solution indexes use the following notation

```
C1{3}(1,:)
 =
   1     4

C1{3}(2,:)
 =
   2     3

C1{3}(3,:)
 =
   3     2
```

One can generate the actual variables `antidiag1` `antidiag2` .. with command evalin

Comment: It works pretty well, except you have to reconsider `C1(1)=[]` for different row and column situations. For `row>col`, `C1(end)=[]`, for `row<col`, `C1(1)=[]` and for `row=col`, `C1(1)=[], C1(end)=[]`

Comment: maybe we can get rid of empty cell elements by `C1 = C1(~cellfun('isempty',C1))`